# Mongoose find objects where array field contains all values in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object that looks like this:

```
let SentenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sentence: { type: String, required: true },
  language: { type: String, required: true },
  tokens: [{ type: String }]
});
```

I have an array that looks like this

```
let words = ['i', 'love', 'you', 'me', 'cheese', 'and'];
```

I would like to find all objects where *all* of the `tokens` are present in this array. This is what i already tried:

```
Sentence.find({ tokens: { $all: words } });
```

Which only returns one result, `i love you me and cheese`, whereas i'd like it to return other results too, like `i love you` and `you love me`.

If i change the operator from `$all` to `$in`, then I get more results than intended because something like `cheese is a food that i love` would also be matched.

I simply want to return all sentences where all the `tokens` strings are present in the above words array. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems what you need to do in this case is kind of weird but you have to do `nin` with `elemMatch` and then top it off with `not` to get there.

The query looks like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  tokens: {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        $nin: [
          "i",
          "love",
          "you",
          "me",
          "cheese",
          "and"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

With this input:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    tokens: [
      "i",
      "love",
      "you",
      "me",
      "cheese",
      "and"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    tokens: [
      "i",
      "love",
      "cheese",
      "and"
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    tokens: [
      "love",
      "you",
      "me",
      "soap"
    ]
  }
]
```

It would return the correct result of:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "tokens": [
      "i",
      "love",
      "you",
      "me",
      "cheese",
      "and"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "tokens": [
      "i",
      "love",
      "cheese",
      "and"
    ]
  }
]
```

as you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cKrM9sqD35b).